# Group By ID in Crystal

Tags: crystal-reports

I have data pulling via a SQL query into Crystal.

For example:

```
ID    Test     Answer
001   Test_A   A
002   Test_B   A
002   Test_B   NULL
002   Test_B   B
003   Test_B   NULL
003   Test_B   NULL
```

Basically on Crystal Syntax, I need to do 2 things:
1. Group by ID
2. Create a formula for ID

For example:

- If ID = 002 and so long as there's at least one value, then Yes
- If ID = 002 and they're all NULL values, then No

Desired output:

```
ID     Test     Answer
001    Test_A   Yes
002    Test_B   Yes
003    Test_B   No
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Grouping by ID should be simple: add a new group using the ID as key. The ID can be a simple field or a formula.
2. Detecting null values can be found out in formulas using `global` or `shared` variables.

Init formular in group header:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
global BooleanVar ThereIsNull := False;
```

Calculation in detail section:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
global BooleanVar ThereIsNull := ThereIsNull or isnull(...);
```

Output in group footer:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
global BooleanVar ThereIsNull;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Where do  I put this in the query?

Comment: It's not in the query, but in the crystal reports document. Do you use an editor?

Comment: Got it! So I apply this in Crystal, which is what I wanted to do - thanks!